# Search string from database containing certain characters laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have name column in my table containing list of business names.

The problem is there are some business names containing - , ' characters.

I am using this query to search the name

```
$names = Brand::where(name, 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->get();
```

Example : a name from database `daddy's barber shop`
If I search this using this term `daddys barber shop` without `'` character, it returns nothing. 
How to ignore the `'` character from database so it will match the `daddy's barber shop` ?
How to achieve this search?

Comment: Looks like you'd want to do a regex search instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can whether go with @Rohit shah answer using whereRaw instead of where, but that is heavy processing especially when you'll have a lot of raws in your table, so everytime the replace charcters is processed.

What I would do if I had that case, is to create an other column in the tabale "name_alt" where i store the names without the unwanted charcters an make the searches on that column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Column_name
FROM
    Table_name
WHERE
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '-',''), ',', ''), ''', '') LIKE '%search_string%'
```

This type of Query might serve your purpose.

Hope this helps you. Let me know in case of any query.